# Javascript data structure for constant string mapping?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What data type(s) would provide easy lookup for a finite mapping of a pair of strings to one string

```
S X S |-> S ?
```

I wish to represent the mapping this way rather than as a function in order to make it easy to extend with simple rules.

Do I need to use arrays, e.g.

```
[ [[S1, S2], S3 ], [[S1, S3], S4 ], ...]
```

to represent the tuples? That seems to make lookups horrid. . . but I know that in ES6 keys can't be objects, so I see no other way..

Comment: keys of es6 Map can be object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/map

Comment: It depends on what you consider easy lookup. Most builtin structures use some form of strict equality for lookups, which means that looking up for anything other than primitives you'll have to keep the obj to do the lookup. You could just concatenate the string tuple which would make it much easier.

Answer (score 2):

A nested map (simple search tree) provides a generic solution:

```js
const map = {
  "one": {
    "one": "11",
    "two": "12"
  },
  "two": {
    "one": "21",
    "two": "22"
  }
};

console.log(map["one"]["one"]); // "11"
console.log(map["one"]["two"]); // "12"
console.log(map["two"]["one"]); // "21"
console.log(map["two"]["two"]); // "22"
```

Alternatively, you can also concatenate two strings into a single key. But you need to prevent key collisions such as `"a" + "ab"` and `"aa" + "b"`, e.g. by prefixing the key with the length of the first string:

```js
const map = {
  "3:oneone": "11",
  "3:onetwo": "12",
  "3:twoone": "21",
  "3:twotwo": "22"
}

function set(map, str1, str2, val) {
  return map[str1.length + ":" + str1 + str2] = val;
}

function get(map, str1, str2) {
  return map[str1.length + ":" + str1 + str2];
}

console.log(get(map, "one", "one")); // "11"
console.log(get(map, "one", "two")); // "12"
console.log(get(map, "two", "one")); // "21"
console.log(get(map, "two", "two")); // "22"
```

If you do not like prefixing with the string length, you could e.g. use a separator `"a" + ":" + "ab"` but would then need to escape the separator character within the two strings. Personally, I prefer the nested map as demonstrated above for its genericity and simplicity.

Comment: I like the generic map as well. In my case, the domain is S^2 where S is finite set of symbols, and image is subset of S. It would be nice to avoid duplicating each rule since order of inputs doesn't matter...